# How to save a ggplot heatmap output as a raster

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a data set which I wish to produce a heat map for and export the heat map as a raster so that I can use in another GIS software. I have the following data set;

```
structure(list(Longitude = c(83.01902, 83.04428, 83.07211, 83.08611, 
83.11934, 83.12175, 83.13665, 83.14032, 83.15158, 83.15324, 83.17485, 
83.17823, 83.19479, 83.21212, 83.22364, 83.24, 83.24301, 83.24766, 
83.24869, 83.25096, 83.26048, 83.26767, 83.27696, 83.28758, 83.28842, 
83.29257, 83.29861, 83.30751, 83.31339, 83.31459, 83.31735, 83.32446, 
83.35895, 83.3939, 83.39481, 83.41, 83.49965, 83.5265, 83.54585, 
83.54642, 83.56225, 83.58743, 83.6327, 83.67486), Latitude = c(27.49143, 
27.53033, 27.54134, 27.589, 27.60669, 27.53022, 27.46776, 27.56822, 
27.50877, 27.63619, 27.67205, 27.54466, 27.51068, 27.69448, 27.41738, 
27.49342, 27.53017, 27.63331, 27.44174, 27.56867, 27.60454, 27.47598, 
27.57293, 27.55558, 27.63096, 27.6531, 27.55854, 27.67777, 27.52301, 
27.55364, 27.4924, 27.59005, 27.60943, 27.62901, 27.67632, 27.51055, 
27.51166, 27.53252, 27.57101, 27.51175, 27.60436, 27.51426, 27.53022, 
27.53555), Total = c(11L, 5L, 8L, 16L, 13L, 5L, 10L, 25L, 4L, 
5L, 1L, 7L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 12L, 4L, 3L, 
7L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 19L, 11L, 9L, 16L, 17L, 
9L, 9L, 18L, 7L, 7L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(Longitude = c(83.01902, 
83.04428, 83.07211, 83.08611, 83.11934, 83.12175, 83.13665, 83.14032, 
83.15158, 83.15324, 83.17485, 83.17823, 83.19479, 83.21212, 83.22364, 
83.24, 83.24301, 83.24766, 83.24869, 83.25096, 83.26048, 83.26767, 
83.27696, 83.28758, 83.28842, 83.29257, 83.29861, 83.30751, 83.31339, 
83.31459, 83.31735, 83.32446, 83.35895, 83.3939, 83.39481, 83.41, 
83.49965, 83.5265, 83.54585, 83.54642, 83.56225, 83.58743, 83.6327, 
83.67486), .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
    23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
    35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-44L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

I have produced a heat map using ggplot with the following code

```
Data <- ggplot(Raptor_Fixed_Table_Sum, aes(x= Longitude, y= Latitude)) +
  geom_point(data=Raptor_Fixed_Table_Sum, mapping=aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, size=Total))+
  xlim(82.8,83.8)+
  ylim(27.35,27.8)


Data + geom_density2d()+ 
  stat_density2d(data=Raptor_Fixed_Table_Sum, aes(fill = ..level..),alpha=0.5, geom = "polygon")+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red")+
  scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE)+
  geom_point(data=Raptor_Fixed_Table_Sum, mapping=aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, size=Total), colour ="blue")
```

I don't know how to go about extracting just the heat map. Ideally I would like it as a raster so that I can save it and use in QGIS to overlay a map of the area.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you have produced isn't a heat map - it's a contour plot. That's much harder to export as a raster. Why not just do the whole thing in R? You can get maps onto a ggplot more easily than you can export a ggplot as a raster

Comment: Oh ok thanks. I struggled to get the open street background map that I wanted into R, I had tried ggmap but was restricted cause of the API key, but will give it another go.